# Python ttk label Error, label undefined

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have written the following code for an alarm clock, found it on GitHub. But in my code it throws up an error saying that the label is not defined.

```
import time as time, os as os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk  # For buttons, labels, frames etc...

root = Tk()  # Creates the tkinter object root
root.title('Alarm Clock')  # Sets the window title
root.geometry('200x200')  # Sets the window dimension


def submit_button():  # The core condition for the alarm clock
     alarm_time = time_entry.get()
     dialog_box()
     #bottom_label.config(text ="The Alarm will Ring at {} ".format(AlarmTime))  #delayed in execution
     current_time = time.strftime('%H:%M')  # Sets the current_time format to Hours:Minutes
     print('The alarm time is: {}' .format(alarm_time))
     while alarm_time != current_time:
         current_time = time.strftime('%H:%M')  # Sets the current_time format to Hours:Minutes
         time.sleep(1)  # To give a delay in while loop 
     if alarm_time == current_time:  # When current_time is alarm time
         os.system('start alarm-music.mp3')  # Play the music from the os
         bottom_label.config(text="Alarm music playing....")
         messagebox.showinfo(title='Alarm Message', message="{}".format(entry2.get()))


def dialog_box():
    alarm_time = time_entry.get()
    messagebox.showinfo("Alarm Clock", "alarm will ring at {}" .format(alarm_time))  # title and display of dialog box.
    bottom_label.config(text = "The alarm time is counting...")  # configures the text below submit button


# Frame creation
alarm_frame = ttk.Frame(root)  # Creates a frame named alarm_frame
alarm_frame.config(height=200, width=200)  # Sets the dimensions of the frame
alarm_frame.pack()

# Alarm Label
alarm_label = ttk.Label(alarm_frame, text = "Enter the alarm time:")  # Creates a label with text Enter alarm time
alarm_label.pack()  # Unpacks the label onto the frame

# Entering time
time_entry = ttk.Entry(alarm_frame, width=30)  
time_entry.insert(3, 'example: 13:15')  
time_entry.pack()  # Unpacks the entry on the frame

 # Message label
message_label = ttk.Label(alarm_frame, text = "Enter message to display:")
message_label.pack()

# Entering Message
message_entry = ttk.Entry(alarm_frame, width = 30)  # Facilitates entering    alarm message
message_entry.pack()  # Unpacks the entry area

# Creation of submit button
submit = ttk.Button(alarm_frame, text = 'submit', command = submit_button())     
submit.pack()  # Unpacks the button onto the frame


# Bottom label creation
bottom_label = ttk.Label(alarm_frame)  # Label(master, **kw)
bottom_label.pack()  # unpacks the bottom_label on the frame

root.mainloop()
```

It says that bottom_label is not defined in dialog_box() why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
...
# Bottom label creation
bottom_label = ttk.Label(alarm_frame)  # Label(master, **kw)
bottom_label.pack()  # unpacks the bottom_label on the frame

# Creation of submit button
submit = ttk.Button(alarm_frame, text = 'submit', command = submit_button())     
submit.pack()  # Unpacks the button onto the frame
...
```

Instead of:

```
...
# Creation of submit button
submit = ttk.Button(alarm_frame, text = 'submit', command = submit_button())     
submit.pack()  # Unpacks the button onto the frame


# Bottom label creation
bottom_label = ttk.Label(alarm_frame)  # Label(master, **kw)
bottom_label.pack()  # unpacks the bottom_label on the frame
...
```

Order matters, you have to initialize `bottom_label` before using it in `command=`.

Comment: Sorry I could not understand it quite clearly, could you explain a little more please?

Comment: I hope it's clear now. Also you may want get rid of that `while` loop.

Comment: Well I figured out that the error was in button handler call back, I have used an unecessary paraenthesis in the call back, in command. After I removed it, the program is working as desired